# ASP.NET MVC jQuery Ajax Error/Exception Handling

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, error-handling

I have a asp.net MVC web application that makes use of jQuery for a number of Ajax calls.  The ajax calls a Controller which catches various Validation Exceptions thrown in stored procedures.  When a validation exception is discovered in a procedure I use the following syntax

```
RAISERROR ('VALIDATION ERROR: xyx is required.', 16, 1)
```

My MVC Controller then catches the SQL Exception, where I do some logging and then rethrown a new Exception(e.Message).

```
catch (SqlException se)
{
    // logging happens

    // exception get rethrown for ajax error handling
    throw new Exception(se.Message);
 }
```

From there, my ajax error handler takes over.

```
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {}
```

In my local Visual Studio Server the ajax error handler retrieves the **desired** following jqXHR.responseText:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>VALIDATION ERROR: xyx is required.</title>
</head>
 ....
```

From there I parse the title and display the validation error.  Works great.

However, when I deploy my code to a hosted IIS server I am getting a generic 500 response in the jqXHR.responseText:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Runtime Error</title>
</head> ....
```

For some reason my shared prod server is handling the Exception differently.  Do you know how I can get both environments to produce the first behavior?

I have tried added the following lines in my web.config but no luck

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="PassThrough">
  <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
  <remove statusCode="502" subStatusCode="-1" />
  <remove statusCode="501" subStatusCode="-1" />
  <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1" />
</httpErrors>
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Correctly setting up error handling in MVC is a sorting of balancing act, at least it has been for me. In my case I ended up defining the custom error messages in both `<system.web><customErrors>` and in `<system.webServer><httpErrors>`. And then of course I had the default `ErrorHandler` (or in my case `ElmahErrorHandler`) in the `Global.asax`

I'm not going to pretend to understand it completely, but I will instead show you what I use.
I thought I had one more piece somewhere in my app but I can't find it at the moment, the views you can probably guess their contents, they are mostly static HTML with the exception of the 500 one that might have a model. In that case I output some more detailed error information depending on the current users role.

I also had to unlock the `httpErrors` node of the machine.config so that the app was able to define it's own custom error paths via the web.config. You can still set your own via the IIS admin tool (versus the `web.config`) but they actually get written to the `machine.config` by matching the app's ID.

**web.config**

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly">
      <!-- Off, RemoteOnly, On -->
      <error statusCode="400" redirect="~/errors/badrequest"/>
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/errors/notfound"/>
      <error statusCode="403" redirect="~/errors/forbidden"/>
      <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/errors/exception"/>
    </customErrors>
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly">
      <!-- Detailed, DetailedLocalOnly, Custom -->
      <remove statusCode="400" subStatusCode="-1"/>
      <error statusCode="400" path="/errors/badrequest" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
      <remove statusCode="403" subStatusCode="-1"/>
      <error statusCode="403" path="/errors/forbidden" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
      <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1"/>
      <error statusCode="500" path="/errors/exception" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
      <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1"/>
      <error statusCode="404" path="/errors/notfound" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
    </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

**global.asax**

```
filters.Add(new Elmah.Contrib.Mvc.ElmahHandleErrorAttribute());
// -- OR --
filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
```

**Error Controller**

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public class ErrorsController : WimsController
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }

    public ActionResult Exception(HandleErrorInfo error = null)
    {
        return View("Error_500", error);
    }

    public ActionResult NotFound()
    {
        return View("Error_404");
    }

    public ActionResult Forbidden()
    {
        return View("Error_403");
    }

    public ActionResult BadRequest()
    {
        return View("Error_400");
    }
}
```